# come back to the default statement after selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I have 4 buttons and when the user clicks on them, I am changing their background color. When a button is clicked, I would like the other buttons to revert to their original background color (black). I've gotten it to work for the first selection, but it doesn't work after that.

How can I restore the default color to the buttons each time a button is clicked?

```
if (data4 == a) {
    $(".button1").css('background-color', '#2EFE2E');
} else if (data4 == b) {
    $(".button2").css('background-color', '#088A08');
} else if (data4 == c) {
    $(".button3").css('background-color', '#088A08');
} else if (data4 == d) {
    $(".button4").css('background-color', '#088A08');
} else {
    $(".button1, .button2, .button3, .button4").css('background-color', 'black');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Return them all to default color before applying the new color to the selected button

```
$(".button1, .button2, .button3, .button4").css('background-color', 'black');
if (data4==a) {
  $(".button1").css('background-color', '#2EFE2E');
}else if(data4==b){
    $(".button2").css('background-color', '#088A08');
}else if(data4==c){
    $(".button3").css('background-color', '#088A08');
}else if(data4==d){
    $(".button4").css('background-color', '#088A08');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your reset is never called when you click a new button, because is is in the "else" part. I would do this (haven't tested it):

```
$(".button1, .button2, .button3, .button4").css('background-color', 'black');
if (data4==a) {
  $(".button1").css('background-color', '#2EFE2E');
}else if(data4==b){
    $(".button2").css('background-color', '#088A08');
}else if(data4==c){
    $(".button3").css('background-color', '#088A08');
}else if(data4==d){
    $(".button4").css('background-color', '#088A08');
}
```